# Drag & Drop Text-Elements on PDF-Documents and save new PDF with dropped Elements

Tags: javascript, c#, html, winforms, pdf

I am working currently on a project and i haven't found a solution how to realize it yet. I am **not** asking for the solution. I would be very thankful if someone could give me some hints or tell me in which direction i could go to reach my goal.

Currently i am thinking about trying to solve it by programming an web-application. But i am not sure if a windows forms application would even be better. I am also open for other solutions.

***My goal is following:***

I have some (real world) documents which are being scanned and afterwards scanned with an OCR-Scanner, which generates some PDF-Documents. 
Next i want to open one of these generated PDF-Files in a User Interface which shows me the PDF. The user should be able to select some (one after another) text-blocks, which are downloaded from a database, and drag them over the pdf and drop it at some position.

Now i want to save or print the pdf with the text-blocks, just as the user sees it. Kind of making a screenshot of the pdf but resulting in a pdf file with the same dimensions as before.
Currently i have no idea how to *"merge"* these two.

Which technologies should i use. What would you recommend me. Would a web-application or something native be better suitable for that purpose.

I have written some kind of mockup to show what i mean. Please put some pdf named "testpdf.pdf" to the same folder if you want to test it. 
It works on Chrome ... not sure about the others.

Thanks a lot

Kerem

```js
var movabelelements=document.getElementsByClassName("moveableElement");
Array.from(movabelelements).forEach(element => {
    dragElement(element);
});

function dragElement(elem){
    var pos1=0,pos2=0,pos3=0,pos4=0;
    elem.onmousedown=dragMouseDown;

    function dragMouseDown(e){
        e=e||window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
        pos3=e.clientX;
        pos4=e.clientY;
        document.onmouseup=closeDragElement;
        document.onmousemove=elementDrag;
    }

    function elementDrag(e){
        e=e||window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
        pos1=pos3-e.clientX;
        pos2=pos4-e.clientY;
        pos3=e.clientX;
        pos4=e.clientY;
        elem.style.top=(elem.offsetTop -pos2)+"px";
        elem.style.left=(elem.offsetLeft-pos1)+"px";
    }

    function closeDragElement(){
        document.omouseup=null;
        document.onmousemove=null;
    }
}
function printPDF(){
    alert('Der Bericht sollte jetzt gedruckt werden');
}
function highLightAllValues(){
    Array.from(movabelelements).forEach(element => {
        element.classList.add("highlighted");
    });
    setTimeout(function(){
        Array.from(movabelelements).forEach(element => {
            element.classList.remove("highlighted");
        });
    }, 1500);
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1,h2{
    text-align:center
}

.pdffile{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

body,html{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#values_list_values{
    padding: 15px;
}

#values_list{
    text-align: center;
}

#values_list_values div{
    margin: 15px;
    border-bottom: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}

#values_list_values div:hover{
    color: red;   
}

#values_list_values div span{
    margin: 10px;
}

.moveableElement{
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 20;
    padding: 20px;
}

.moveableElement:hover{
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: red;
    cursor: move;
}

#values_list{
    position: relative;
    width: 20%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

#pdfFileWrapper{
    width: 80%;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}

#highLightAllValuesButton{
    width: 90%;
    display: inline-block; 
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.highlighted{
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: red;
    border-width: 2px;
}

#printButtonArea{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    width: 20%;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
}

#printButtonArea button{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Vorschau</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vorschau.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Druckvorschau PDF</h1>
    
    <div id="pdfFileWrapper">
        <object class="pdffile" data="testpdf.pdf" type="application/pdf">
            alt : <a href="testpdf.pdf">PDF-Vorschau Fehlgeschlagen - Bitte anderen Browser Probieren</a>
        </object>
    </div>
    <div id="values_list">
        <div id="printButtonArea">
                <button onclick="printPDF()">Print</button>
        </div>
        <h2>Werte aus der Datenbank</h2>
        <button id="highLightAllValuesButton" onclick="highLightAllValues()">Show all text blocks</button>
        <div id="values_list_values">
            <div>
                <h3>One</h3>
                <span>xy</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h3>Material ID</h3>
                <span>12</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h3>Some Other ID</h3>
                <span>some other id</span>
            </div>
            <div>
            <h3>Identifikation</h3>
            <span>lastvalue</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="1" style="top:200px;left:100px" class="moveableElement">
        Example value
    </div>
    <div id="2" style="top:250px;left:150px"class="moveableElement">
        Car One
    </div>
    <div id="3" style="top:300px;left:200px" class="moveableElement">
        <span>whatever</span>
    </div>
    <div id="4" style="top:350px;left:250px" class="moveableElement">number 12

    </div>
</body>
<script src="vorschau.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The situation has not changed much over the years it is currently not allowed to use overlays inside the Chrome PDF Viewer. So here is the nice demo with my annotations.
[image]

And if we switch off the PDF contents layer we can see the overlay is unaffected you may write on this side of PDF window but you cannot write inside that sandbox in Chromium's etc.
[image]

And thus it cannot be included in any save.

[image]

The good news is that PDF.js is not a pure PDF viewer so has a different means of annotation layering so it should be possible to work within FireFox or a personalised PDF.js. Just beware at times it has its own ideas about orientation.

[image]

Thus the **Answer** to "supply hints", has to be, use a commercial product that has the ability to allow JavaScript programming of its own annotation layers. There are many offerings from Adobe, Apryse and other PDF viewer vendors.